# Parametrize an implicit polynomial with multiple variables

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

How can you parametrize an arbitrary implicit polynomial of the form:

$C_1x^{A} + c_2y^{B} = C$

And in particular:

$x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}$

Comment: See [Astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid) on wikipedia.

Comment: Also [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08308.pdf) has a rational parametrization: e.g. $x^{\frac23}+y^{\frac23}=1$ is $x(t)=(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})^3, y(t)=-(\frac{2t}{1+t^2})^3$